# How to place a regular expression in a perl map operation using the conditional operator

Tags: regex, perl, mapping, ternary-operator

Hi I try to shorten a loop construct using a map operation and a conditional operator with a regular expression, but get not the right results. I think the reason for the failure is the difference between the assigment and the regexp operator (`=` vs. `=~` ). What is the right formulation for this approach.

**Long version:**

```perl
print("TABLE.BEGIN\n");
while(my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
   $row++;
   for my $ix (0..$#data) {
       my $val = $data[$ix];
       if ($val) {
           $val =~ s/\t/[:TAB:]/g;
       } else {
           $val = 'NULL';
       }
       $data[$ix] = $val;
   }
   print "ROW: $row\t",join("\t",@data),"\n";
}
print("END.TABLE\n");
```

**Long version result**

```
TABLE.BEGIN
ROW: 1  12  79  1   PhoViComp   2017-05-22-PhoViComp    2017-05-22  32632   rostock HRO punjabi 2017-05-22-PhoViComp    /net/server/path/
END.TABLE
```

**Short version**

```perl
print("TABLE.BEGIN\n");
my $row=0;
while(my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    $row++;
    @data = map { $_ ? s/\t/[:TAB:]/g : 'NULL' } @data;
    print "ROW: $row\t",join("\t",@data),"\n";
}
print("END.TABLE\n");
```

**Short version result**

```
TABLE.BEGIN
ROW: 1                                              
END.TABLE
```

Comment: The conditional operator is but one ternary operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In list context, `s/\t/[:TAB:]/g` returns `1` and nothing otherwise. You need to return the modified `$_`.

---

So you had something close to

```
for (@data) {
    my $val = $_;
    if (defined($val)) {
        $val =~ s/\t/[:TAB:]/g;
    } else {
        $val = 'NULL';
    }

    $_ = $val;
}
```

The `map` version would be

```
@data = map {
    my $val = $_;
    if (defined($val)) {
        $val =~ s/\t/[:TAB:]/g;
    } else {
        $val = 'NULL';
    }

    $val
} @data;
```

Of course, you could have written

```
$_ = defined($_) ? s/\t/[:TAB:]/rg : 'NULL' for @data;            # 5.14+
```

The equivalent (but slower) `map` version would be

```
@data = map { defined($_) ? s/\t/[:TAB:]/rg : 'NULL' } @data;     # 5.14+
```

Comment: $_ = defined($_) ? s/\t/[:TAB:]/rg : 'NULL' for @data;  Works for me! Is it slower than a common loop?

Comment: No, `$_ = defined($_) ? s/\t/[:TAB:]/rg : 'NULL' for @data;` is not any slower than `for (@data) { $_ = defined($_) ? s/\t/[:TAB:]/rg : 'NULL'; }`, if that's what you mean. Just two ways of writing the same thing.